# Understanding Map Reduce - work flow in the below code

Tags: python, sum, reduce

*(Code attached at the end)*

I could not get my head around the below code for word count problem. To my understanding (please correct If I am wrong), mapper would generate output on a set of lines in tuples,

```
"the", 1
"wheels", 1
"on", 1
"the", 1
"bus", 1
"go", 1
"round", 1
"and", 1
"round", 1
```

I am trying to understand how the python sum function would work on these individual tuples, I have seen examples of sum on lists but can't really find much on tuples. Also shouldn't there be a loop in reducer too to ensure it performs an action against all words?

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re

WORD_REGEX = re.compile(r"\b\w+\b")

class Wordcount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        words = WORD_REGEX.findall(line)
        for word in words:
            yield (word.lower(), 1)

    def reducer(self, word, counts):

        yield(word, sum(counts))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Wordcount.run()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum on a tuple works exactly the same as sum on a list.  In general tuples are basically just immutable lists.

Because this Wordcount class is derived from the parent MRJob class, we inherit the run function.  This function does some aggregation for us behind a layer of abstraction.

The mapper function works about how you said, returning each tuple in your list one at a time using a python generator function.

So the MRJob package's run function will call mapper on each line, aggregating the information for you so the reducer is exposed to the arguments (word, counts), where word is a word from your text input, and counts is a list of the values returned by mapper.  i.e. Wordcount.run() would (after the mapping step) make the function call: reducer("the", [1,1]), and reducer would then "return" the tuple ("the", 2) (since sum([1,1])=2).  This would be done for every word in your text input.

It's worth noting that the MrJob function allows you to define a combiner function which acts as a middleman between mapping and reducing and might help understand the process (and also makes complex jobs a bit faster).  Below is a link to an example from the MRJob documentation that further explains each of these functions:

https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/concepts.html